# Select nearest entity which isn't the owner of a projectile

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm working on creating a homing missile which targets any flying object. However, the main limitation is that the missile can only be launched from the ground because it tends to track whoever shot the missile if the owner is in-flight.

The current command that I am using is:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:firework_rocket,nbt={ShotAtAngle:1b,FireworksItem:{tag:{Tags:['guided_missile']}}}] at @s if entity @e[limit=1,sort=nearest,nbt={FallFlying:1b},distance=1..] at @e[limit=1,sort=nearest,type=!minecraft:firework_rocket] run tp @s ^ ^ ^3 facing entity @e[limit=1,sort=nearest,nbt={FallFlying:1b},distance=1..]
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to exclude the owner from the entity selector without using user-specific data.

As a side note which readers might find useful, I'm thinking of using something similar to this function that is used as a proximity fuze for missiles.

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:firework_rocket,nbt={Life:0,ShotAtAngle:1b}] store result score @s missileowneruuid run data get entity @s Owner[0]

execute as @e[type=!minecraft:firework_rocket] store result score @s missileowneruuid run data get entity @s UUID[0]

execute as @e[type=minecraft:firework_rocket,nbt={ShotAtAngle:1b}] at @s if entity @e[distance=..3,type=!minecraft:firework_rocket] unless score @s missileowneruuid = @e[type=!minecraft:firework_rocket,distance=..3,sort=nearest,limit=1] missileowneruuid run data modify entity @s LifeTime set value 1
```

Comment: could you track the UUID of the player and make it not track them?